# how to display the image stored in mysql database

Tags: php, html

Here is the simple code what i tried.

I am not able to display the image presented in database

Please help me in this regard.

I am using two files

1) db.php
   This is for connecting mysql database and getting a record.

**Images will be saved in a jp2 format.**

2) test.php

Displaying record using php.

**If images are saved in JP2 format then then how can i convert these images and display into a web page.

If iam using this code some junk(bytecode say) is displaying ian a web page**

This is my db.php

```
<?php
function getResidentPhoto() {
    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root@19211');
    if (!$dbcnx) {
        die('<p>Unable to connect to the ' . 'database server at this time.</p>'
            );
    }
    if (!@mysql_select_db('finaldb')) {
        die('<p>Unable to locate the ' . 'database at this time.</p>');
    }

    $selectrc = 'select BPFT_Photo from photo_templates limit 1';
    $result = @mysql_query($selectrc, $dbcnx);
    if (!$result) {
        die('<p>Error performing query: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
    } else {

    }
    $n = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($n > 0) {
        $Photo_Details = $row['BPFT_Photo'];
        return $Photo_Details;
    }
}
?>
```

and my test.php is

```
<?php
echo' <html>';
echo'<body>';
echo' <table>';
echo' <tr><td>';

$residentPhoto = getResidentPhoto();
$image_type_to_mime_type0 =image_type_to_mime_type($residentPhoto)
header('Content-type:$image_type_to_mime_type0');

echo' '.$residentPhoto;

echo'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
echo'</table>';
echo'</body>';
echo'</html>';
?>
```

Comment: What, if anything, is happening instead?

Comment: What error are you getting? How are we supposed to know what `$row['BPFT_Photo']` contains?

Comment: why don't you store image path into database and upload image into your server.

Comment: I would guess your `test.php` should only calls `header(...);echo $residentPhoto;`, like Niet said.

Comment: have you used: header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg', true );

Comment: Try This : img src="<?php echo $residentPhoto; ?>" width="175" height="200" />

Comment: Always run first your sql queries through an echo if you try something. See what the output is (if you have a php myadmin, even better) If it returns something, try to print out the array it returns and see if there is something wrong there. Also I dont see you including your db file into the test.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the `content-type` header, I'm going to guess that `$residentPhoto` is raw image data. If that is the case, then there should be *absolutely no output* other than the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

In test.php you should include or require the db.php file.
make sure the path of image is given and make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing HTML with the actual image.

You just have to output the image in a separate file, which you have to include in your html with an "img" tag.

For example:

```
<img src="image.php?imageId=1" alt="Image" />
```

There is another solution but it has some drawbacks:
You can embedd image data in your HTML by using Data URLs: http://davidwalsh.name/data-uri-php but this will increase your HTML code size and (maybe) you will get problems with older browsers (IE < 8).